# sharepoint workflow solution not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, solution

i have made a sequential workflow in visual studio 2010.
the workflow is working fine on me local machine. i have packaged it to a solution and uploaded it to our intranet. using site settings solution and then add solution and activate it. when i go to site features i don't see me solution and it's not working on the list i have made it for. anyone knows how to fix this ? i'm using sharepoint2010 foundation.
the language i have made it in is english and the site where im trying to install it is Dutch.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the workflow is published.

[This link may also be of help](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36383/imported-workflow-activated-as-feature-does-not-show-up-in-manage-site-features). There is a slight chance your problem might have to do with localization issues.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but i made the workflow in visual studio so it's already a .wsp file. i added it to the new site like i told above. but then it's not in the site features to activate it ..... really strange because i have a solution with eventreceiver that's workign o nthe same site also installed with a .wsp file.

Comment: Is the feature definition in VS set for a site feature? It might be a feature for another level.

Comment: this might be a stupid question but where can i find the feature definition ?

Comment: It's in the "Features" folder of the project. There will be a project item there called "Feature1", and if you haven't changed any settings, double clicking on it will open a visual editor. There you can change the feature name and description as it will appear in a Sharepoint site. There is also a combobox where you select the scope of the feature (i.e.: farm, site collection, site or web application).

Comment: title = workflowleaveapplication and scope = site, so i guess that's right

Comment: Scope=site means it's a site collection feature, actually. If you want it to be a site feature, choose "web".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29314/discussion-between-renan-and-user1652050)